# What is the meaning (and origin) of the word 'peck' in the expression 'bomb peck' (BrE)?

Tags: meaning, british-english, colloquialisms

Someone used the words **'bomb peck'** in conversation to me yesterday and I queried what they meant. I have found the expression being used colloquially online but with no explanation of what 'peck' means or what the origin of the saying is.

> I remember the bomb peck between Wilkinson Street and Miller Street, the Germans must have been aiming for Millers and the factories in Bracebridge Street and Aston Brook Street.

[Birmingham History](https://birminghamhistory.co.uk/forum/index.php?threads/bomb-pecks.36/)

> When the Second World War was over, urban Birmingham was in a sorry state. Thousands upon thousands of buildings were destroyed with bombs, and many more damaged through near-misses and fires. Amongst all of the devastation, sadness, and determination to rebuild, little sparks of joy flared up. The ruins that were left behind became something that defined the childhoods of a couple of generations of Brummies. Kids started playing in the wastelands and shells of houses. They became the **"bomb pecks".**

[Birmingham Mail](https://www.birminghammail.co.uk/news/nostalgia/birmingham-kids-played-bomb-pecks-24587988)

It was my next door neighbour who introduced me to the term and she was remembering her childhood in the 1960s when she lived in a 'back to back' in Birmingham.

Can anyone tell me what the word 'peck' means (when used in this context) and what is the origin of that meaning ?

Comment: The [Birmingham History Forum](https://birminghamhistory.co.uk/forum/index.php?search/1189361/&q=bomb+pecks&t=post&o=date) seems less than forthcoming on the origins of the term.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's surprising. (I wasn't aware of them.) Surely they have a few persons sixty years old and over, who could assist ?

Comment: It should be noted that "peck" is, in one sense, a unit of volume equal to one quarter of a bushel.  I can see how this metric might have been applied to small shell holes.

Answer (score 4):

Among the meanings of *peck* are:

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/peck)
> *peck*: in British English
> VERB:
> to strike with the beak or with a pointed instrument
> (transitive)   to dig (a hole) by pecking
> NOUN:
> a quick stroke, as in pecking
> a hole or mark made by or as by pecking

Hence a peck is a hole that has been pecked into the ground by a bomb

Answer (score 3):

I’m 75 years young and I remember vividly in Aston Birmingham early 1950s saying *do you want to come and play up on the Bomb Peck* meaning shelled houses and flattened land.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It should be a comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 2):

There is a credible suggestion at the [Birmingham History](https://birminghamhistory.co.uk/forum/index.php?threads/bomb-pecks.36/page-4#post-742299) site.

The suggestion is that a bomb peck was distinctive in that it lacked a crater:

> **cookie273uk  Apr 15, 2019 #63** I'd never heard of the expression 'bomb
> peck' until I joined this Forum, we always referred to them a Bomb
> sites, where did the expression 'peck' come from ?
>
> **sospiri Apr 15, 2019 #64** Likewise, Eric, perhaps because there was no actual hole on the site
> next door to us, where five terraced houses were taken down. None of
> them had cellars due to the high water table. […]
>
> It would have been difficult for the average bomb to make much of a
> peck in those conditions!

This is in the sense of a “peck” being a lesser piece of damage than what might be expected:

OED

> **2.** The impression or mark made by pecking; a prick, a hole; a dot; **a slight surface injury.**
>
> 1852   J. Wiggins Pract. Embanking Lands 15   Raising a bank of great
> bulk, turfing or gravelling the sea face, and mending every little
> ‘peck’ or injury as it occurs.

Yes, I realise that there is little difference if your house is flattened or replaced by a crater, but this idea of "peck" seems to be British understatement.